# XML to Object Unmarshalling using JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

I need to Unmarshal XML to Java Object, I have tried with below code. Its create an Object but set all value as a null. code for same:

```
 @XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Dispatch implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Integer dispatchId;
    private Order order;

    /**
     * @return the dispatchId
     */
    public Integer getDispatchId() {
        return dispatchId;
    }

    /**
     * @param dispatchId
     *            the dispatchId to set
     */
    public void setDispatchId(Integer dispatchId) {
        this.dispatchId = dispatchId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the order
     */
    public Order getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    /**
     * @param order
     *            the order to set
     */
    public void setOrder(Order order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ""+this.dispatchId;
    }
}
```

I have Dispatch Class with other sub class,  i need to convert XML to Java Object. Code for same:

```
Public class UnmarshalExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String xmlString = "<ns1:dispatch xmlns:ns1=\"http://service.order.com\"><ns1:dispatchId>1</ns1:dispatchId><ns1:order><ns1:totalAmount>1000.0</ns1:totalAmount></ns1:order></ns1:dispatch>";

        Dispatch dispatch = (Dispatch) JAXB.unmarshal(
                new StringReader(xmlString), Dispatch.class);

        System.out.println(dispatch);
    }

}
```

**As a output it will return null**.

Can any one tell me whats wrong thing in my code?

Comment: Please post XML contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is odd, I pasted you code and ran and it produces dispatchId 1:

Dispatch class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Dispatch implements java.io.Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Integer dispatchId;

   /**
    * @return the dispatchId
    */
   public Integer getDispatchId() {
       return dispatchId;
   }

   /**
    * @param dispatchId
    *            the dispatchId to set
    */
   public void setDispatchId(Integer dispatchId) {
       this.dispatchId = dispatchId;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return ""+this.dispatchId;
   }
}
```

Test class

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXB;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String xmlString = "<ns1:dispatch xmlns:ns1=\"http://service.order.com\"><ns1:dispatchId>1</ns1:dispatchId><ns1:order><ns1:totalAmount>1000.0</ns1:totalAmount></ns1:order></ns1:dispatch>";

    Dispatch dispatch = (Dispatch) JAXB.unmarshal(
            new StringReader(xmlString), Dispatch.class);

    System.out.println(dispatch);
  }
}
```

output is

```
1
```

Comment: I made a change but its return null as a dispatch Id.

Comment: That is odd, I pasted you code and ran and it produces dispatchId 1 see edited answer

Comment: I dont know why its returning null value even after copy your code.

Comment: Dear Sharonbn, I have tried same xml without namespace,its return 1 but when i use namespace in XML at that time its gives me null value.

Answer (score 1):

The order is of the type Order. We don't see any code of this class.
This is probably the cause of it as well. You may not provide decent data for the Order to be constructed.

To see how namespaces are used: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/applying-namespace-during-jaxb-unmarshal.html

Comment: I have remove order ref from dispatch class and also remove all values from xml related to order class so now i have only Dispatch Class with dispatchId,but result is same.